# gridland metro hackerrank matrix in c

Tags: c, matrix

i wrote this code in c and i can't figure out why it doesn't work so help me please .
here is the question :
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gridland-metro

```
int main() {
    long int n,m,k,c1,c2,r,comp=0;

    scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&n,&m,&k);
    long int mat[n][m];
    for(long int i=0;i<k;i++) {
        scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&r,&c1,&c2);

        for(long int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            for(long int j=1;j<=m;j++) {
                if(j<c2 && j>c1 && i==r)
                {
                    mat[i][j]=1;
                } else {
                    mat[i][j]=0;                     
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(long int b=1;b<=n;b++){
        for(int f=1;f<=m;f++){
            if(mat[b][f]==0)
            {
                comp++;
            } 
        }
    }
    printf("%ld",comp);  
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that arrays are ["base 0"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) in C. You are writing outside of the bounds of the array.

```
long int mat[n][m];
for(long int i=0;i<k;i++){
    scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&r,&c1,&c2);

    for(long int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(long int j=1;j<=m;j++){
             if(j<c2 && j>c1 && i==r)
             {
                 mat[i][j]=1; /* HERE */
```

Change

```
    for(long int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(long int j=1;j<=m;j++){
```

to

```
    for(long int i=1;i<n;i++){
        for(long int j=1;j<m;j++){
```

The same for

```
 for(long int b=1;b<=n;b++){
         for(int f=1;f<=m;f++){
             if(mat[b][f]==0)
```

Also, `main()` is not a valid signature, change to `int main(void)`

Comment: thank you Keine Lust, i tried that but it still doesn't give the required output .

Comment: Whats your current output and whats your desired output?

Comment: my current output is 9 and the desired output is also 9 but when i try to submit it it fails all the tests expet for the two first tests in the hackerrank website  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gridland-metro

Comment: @HadjerChikouche That's because of the constraints in the problem statement, i.e., `1 ≤ n,m ≤ 10E9`. You'll need to consider reading in a data type that can handle very large numbers such as a `char[]`. There are other things to consider too. I've written more tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43766646/314897) for a Java solution, but they also apply in C too.